# build.xml for ivy in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, build, ivy

I am trying to integrate Apache Ivy in a Netbeans web app project.

My `build.xml` file follows the netbeans tutorial:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqIvy

Specifically:

```
     <target name="-ivy-retrieve">
        <ivy:retrieve/> <!-- Load dependencies to the project -->
        <pathconvert property="ivy.classpath.computed" dirsep="/" pathsep=":">
            <path>
                <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
            </path>
            <map from="${basedir}${file.separator}" to=""/>
        </pathconvert>
        <propertyfile file="nbproject/project.properties">
            <entry operation="=" key="ivy.classpath" value="${ivy.classpath.computed}"/>
        </propertyfile>
    </target>
    <target name="-pre-compile" depends="-ivy-retrieve"/>
    <target name="-pre-compile-single" depends="-ivy-retrieve"/>
    <target name="-post-clean">
        <delete dir="lib"/>
    </target>
```

Strangely, this updates `ivy.classpath` in the `nbprojects.project.properties` file but I can't seem to get the build's `WEB-INF/lib` folder to get populated with the `.jar`'s that are listed as dependencies.

Strangely, I had this working the other day and was able to populate the build's `WEB-INF/lib` folder and now when I remove the dependency, the same jar files are included in the build (rather than removing them).

Any suggestions on how to change the `build.xml` file? Or anything else that will get Ivy successfully integrated into my build process (Ivy is detected: I see "resolution report" and "retrieving" in the output while building).

Some things I've tried:
I played around with different options in the above linked tutorial (tried including: 
`<property name="ivy.lib.dir" value="web/WEB-INF/lib/"/>` in the `-ivy-retrieve` task or adding the `<ivy:resolve/>` task before `<ivy:retrieve/>`)

Comment: Another optimization to consider is use of the **cachpath** task, instead of **retrieve**: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ivy:retrieve` [task](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/use/retrieve.html) has a `sync` property which removes not longer relevant dependencies.
Also, doing a `clean and build` helps.